# Notice: Uninitialized string offset при обращении к последнему символу

Tags: php

```
function get_sing() {
    $sings="1!2@3#4$5%6^7&8*9_0+ ";
    return $sings[random_int(0, mb_strlen($sings))];
}
```

Когда функция возвращает число или спецсимвол то предупреждений нет. Но если вернет пробел(в конце строки $sings), то выдает **Notice:** **Uninitialized string offset** Не критично, работе не особо мешает, но напрягает. Или же лучше по другому реализовать возврат пробела?

Comment: mb_strlen($sings)) **- 1**

Comment: И не "поет" (`sings`) а "знаки" - `signs`.

Comment: @u_mulder спасибо))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отключать не надо, лучше исправьте ошибку. Длина строки равна количеству символов в строке, а позиции символов считаются начиная с 0, поэтому максимальный индекс будет равен длина - 1.